# Not able to format bootstrap media

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to format data as image then Content and on below line time date shoud be shown.
I tried following code but it is not showing next to image.I am using bootstreap 3.2.0

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<li>
<div class="media">
      <div class="media-left">
        <a href="Profile?id=12963">
          <img class="media-object" data-src="www.holder.js/64x64" alt="Image">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="media-heading"><a href="Profile?id=12963">USER</a> like your  <a href="Post?id=">post</a></div>
        <p>
          Yesterday 20:10
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</li>
  <div class="yes" id="74" style="visibility: hidden"></div>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder, how do you expect your code to work without including bootstrap css file.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.3/holder.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="Profile?id=12963">
      <img class="media-object" src="www.holder.js/64x64" alt="Image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="media-heading"><a href="Profile?id=12963">USER</a> like your <a href="Post?id=">post</a>
    </div>
    <p>
      Yesterday 20:10
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="yes" id="74" style="visibility: hidden"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I have not included here in my code i have included `bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Have you tried running my answer. Is it working as you expect?

Comment: Then just confirm that your css file is linked properly. You can check it by clicking on css file link by viewing source code in web browser.

Comment: Yes that is there.